# How to do a cumulative with a duplicate value

Tags: powerbi, dax

[http://uupload.ir/view/v2t_capture.png]                                        We have 2 tables with 2 columns:

1. table location ->column ->city ,province
2. table sales column ->actual sales

```
table location : table sales 
province  city       id     sales
tehran    eslamshar  1      100
tehran    rey        2      500
hamedan   tefresh    3      500
esfahan   esahan     4      400
gilan     rasht      5      400
gilan     rar        6      900
```

I want to calculate  80% of total sales in each city and each province 
it means if we have 2800 total sale in  whole province, we want just show province that cut off 80 % of sales:

I use this measure but it has one problem that duplicate value does not count in a cumulative sum.

If I have two same sale like 900 it does not count in cumulative and it ignores it.

```
Cumulative Total =
IF (
    NOT ( ISBLANK ( [sales] ) ),
    CALCULATE (
        [sales],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( DimLocation[Province] ),
            CALCULATE ( [sales], VALUES ( DimLocation[Province] ) ) <= [sales]
        )
    )
)
```

Expected Result:

```
        sales   cumulative
tehran  800 800
shiraz  200 1000
ghom    200 400
markazi 300 500
```

Output:

```
tehran  800 800
shiraz  200 1000
ghom    200 1000
markazi 300 500
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data that matches the expected result?

Comment: i put link for more explain http://uupload.ir/view/v2t_capture.png

 i want yellow result for Cumulative Sum
but i got red result for Cumulative Sum
As I mentioned above this measure ignore duplicate value (In this example, only one of the 200 is calculated)

Comment: In summary, how cumulative aggregation based on the province's column is obtained by the highest amount to the lowest value, so that all values, even duplicates, are counted in cumulative aggregates

Comment: You still have not provided sample data and output that actually match! for example "markazi" is not in the sample data!

Comment: could you please ignore all of above detail .i have a table in this  link : with two column city and sales
https://pasteboard.co/IoRmArs.png

how to write a measure to cumulative sales?
i want a result exactly commutative column in the link https://pasteboard.co/IoRmArs.png
Two points to consider :1 - Based on the amount of sort from the highest to the lowest 2-calculate duplicate values ​​like 800 in cumulative

Answer (score 0):

For a running total you could create this measure:

```
RT Province Sales := 
VAR _current = SELECTEDVALUE ( DimLocation[Province] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Sales], 
        DimLocation[Province] <= _current , 
        ALL ( DimLocation[Province] )
    )
```

Comment: I Try this but As i said i  want the output lik :http://uupload.ir/files/cxjj_capture2.png
sort by value 
your answer is:  
 http://uupload.ir/files/8v2_capture3.png
i want tehran get 1900 .
it means commutative by sortetd value

Comment: it means : I want to show the cities that their cumulative sum has reached 70% of the total .this is shown is this link http://uupload.ir/files/k4bu_capture4.png  
the yellow city reached the 70% of total sales

Comment: I want to show the cities that have reached seventy percent of the total sales (from top to bottom based on the amount).